# Print a string reversed in C

Tags: c, string, reverse

I'm coding a program that takes some files as parameters and prints all lines reversed. The problem is that I get unexpected results:

If I apply it to a file containing the following lines

```
one
two
three
four
```

I get the expected result, but if the file contains

```
september
november
december
```

It returns

```
rebmetpes
rebmevons
rebmeceds
```

And I don't understand why it adds a "s" at the end

Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void reverse(char *word);

int main(int argc, char *argv[], char*envp[]) {
    /* No arguments */
    if (argc == 1) {
        return (0);
    }

    FILE *fp;

    int i;
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        fp = fopen(argv[i],"r"); // read mode

        if( fp == NULL )
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error, no file");
        }

        else
        {
            char line [2048];
/*read line and reverse it. the function reverse it prints it*/
            while ( fgets(line, sizeof line, fp) != NULL )
                reverse(line);  
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }

    return (0);
}

void reverse(char *word)
{
    char *aux;
    aux = word;
    /* Store the length of the word passed as parameter */
    int longitud;
    longitud = (int) strlen(aux);

    /* Allocate memory enough ??? */
    char *res = malloc( longitud * sizeof(char) );

    int i;

    /in this loop i copy the string reversed into a new one
    for (i = 0; i < longitud-1; i++)
    {
        res[i] = word[longitud - 2 - i];
    }

    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", res);
    free(res);
}
```

(NOTE: some code has been deleted for clarity but it should compile)

Comment: when you malloc for string, measuring length using strlen(), you need +1 for NULL terminator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forget to terminate your string with `\0` character. In reversing the string `\0` becomes your first character of reversed string. First allocate memory for one more character than you allocated

```
char *res = malloc( longitud * sizeof(char) + 1);
```

And the try this

```
for (i = 0; i < longitud-1; i++)
{
    res[i] = word[longitud - 2 - i];
}
res[i] = '\0'; // Terminating string with '\0'
```

Comment: Yes, but `strlen` gives you the length without the trailing zero, so you should `malloc(longitud + 1)` to have room for the `'\0'`. (The `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1.) Alternatively you can use the precision modifier in the format string to write out at most `longitud` chars like so: `printf("%.*s\n", longitud - 1, res);`

Comment: @MOehm; I missed `char *res = malloc( longitud * sizeof(char) );` line. Adding to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think I know the problem, and it's a bit of a weird issue.

Strings in C are zero terminated. This means that the string "Hi!" in memory is actually represented as `'H','i','!','\0'`. The way `strlen` etc then know the length of the string is by counting the number of characters, starting from the first character, before the zero terminator. Similarly, when printing a string, `fprintf` will print all the characters until it hits the zero terminator.

The problem is, your `reverse` function never bothers to set the zero terminator at the end, which it needs to since you're copying characters into the buffer character by character. This means it runs off the end of your allocated `res` buffer, and into undefined memory, which just happened to be zero when you hit it (`malloc` makes no promises of the contents of the buffer you allocate, just that it's big enough). You *should* get different behaviour on Windows, since I believe that in debug mode, `malloc` initialises all buffers to 0xcccccccc.

So, what's happening is you copy september, reversed, into `res`. This works as you see, because it just so happens that there's a zero at the end.

You then free `res`, then `malloc` it again. Again, by chance (and because of some smartness in `malloc`) you get the same buffer back, which already contains "rebmetpes". You then put "november" in, reversed, which is slightly shorter, hence your buffer now contains "rebmevons".

So, the fix? Allocate another character too, this will hold your zero terminator (`char *res = malloc( longitud * sizeof(char) + 1);`). After you reverse the string, set the zero terminator at the end of the string (`res[longitud] = '\0';`).

Answer (score 1):

there are two errors there, the first one is that you need one char more allocated (all chars for the string + 1 for the terminator)

```
    char *res = malloc( (longitud+1) * sizeof(char) );
```

The second one is that you have to terminate the string:

```
   res[longitud]='\0';
```

You can terminate the string before entering in the loop because you know already the size of the destination string.

Note that using `calloc` instead of `malloc` you will not need to terminate the string as the memory gets alreay zero-initialised

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, it solved my problem. I read something about the "\0" in strings but wasn't very clear, which is now after reading all the answers (all are pretty good). Thank you all for the help.